# Angular model field not updated on subscribe

Tags: angular

Simplified I got a view:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<tr>
  <td>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="profile.FirstName">
  </td>
  <td>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="profile.LastName">
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

A component where the constructor creates a blank profile and the ngOnInit checks for changes:

```
profile: Profile;
sub: any;
constructor(private serv: ProfileService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.profile = new Profile('', '');
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    const id = params['id'];
    this.serv.getProfile(id).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.profile = res;
      // this.profile.LastName = res.LastName; doesn't work either
    });
  });
}
```

On console the right profile is logged, but the table fields are not updated. What is wrong?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: It should be working fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4sxe7t?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole problem was related to PascalCase vs CamalCase. The assignment in the subscription does not fail while the REST call will pass the attributes in CamelCase with the properties of the Profile class in PascalCase.

```
this.serv.getProfile(id).subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
  this.profile = res; // THIS WILL NOT FAIL
});
```

Hence FirstName, LastName, etc. are never assigned.

Answer (score 0):

What angular is looking for in order to trigger its binding is a reference change.

You're not changing the reference when you assign like this:

```
this.profile.LastName = res.LastName;
```

what you wanna do is using the spread operator like this:

```
this.profile = { ...this.profile, lastName: res.lastName }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks valid and view should be updated. So it looks like you are using [`onPush` Change Detection Strategy](https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4). If yes, so you need to run change detection explicitly:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'yourSlector',
  template: `<!-- The code is omitted for the brevity -->`,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CounterComponent { 

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
          const id = params['id'];
          this.serv.getProfile(id).subscribe(res => {
              console.log(res);
              this.profile = res;
              this.cdr.detectChanges();          
          });
      });
   }
}
```

Please, see [a work stackblitz example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/workshop-angular-2way-ngmodel-7r9xzd?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: This works fine for {{profile.FirstName}} constuctions, but not for  [(ngModel)]="profile.FirstName". Something else missing?

Comment: @Gerard could you create a stackblitz example?

Comment: Rather newbie..., can you? Switched to ReactiveFormsModule: this.sub = this.serv.getProfile(this.id).subscribe(p => {this.editForm.setValue(p); }); Works fine! Perhaps it is a bit strange to change input fields on the fly (if not pristine)

Comment: So no ChangeDetectionStrategy changes needed. Also works on subscribe: ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.getAsyncData().subscribe(p => (this.person = p));
  } getAsyncData() {
    // Fake slow async data
    return of({
      name: 'Moonwalker'
    }).pipe(delay(2000));
  }

Comment: @Gerard great!:)